# How to call php soap client __dorequest

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I've been stuck on this for more than 24 hours. Any information I find online is not relevant to my requirement. Basically, I need to edit the XML before sending it the server. However, I can't figure out how to do this with a wsdl file. I need to edit the xml before sending it. Research online shows these parameters;

request - The XML SOAP request.
location - The URL to request.
action - The SOAP action.
version - The SOAP version.

I'm using this;

```
$response = $client->__doRequest('','http://hiddenlink','myMethod','1');
echo $response;
```

What is the request when using a wsdl file.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the solution to change the header that has to send in SOAP Request, Extending the __doRequest solved it.

```
    class MSSoapClient extends SoapClient {

      function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) {
        $header = '<SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:AuthenticationHeader>
        <ns1:Username>XXXX</ns1:Username>
        <ns1:Password>XXXX</ns1:Password>
        <ns1:Function>XXX</ns1:Function>
        <ns1:TimeOutMilliSec>4000</ns1:TimeOutMilliSec>
        </ns1:AuthenticationHeader>
        </SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body>';
        $request = str_replace('<SOAP-ENV:Body>', $header, $request);

        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
      }

$client = new MSSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1, "exceptions" => 0, 'use' => SOAP_LITERAL));
```

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Comment: Please ad some description